# chrome changing cookie path

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, cookies

I have a web application (ASP.NET MVC3) which uses the jquery ui tab control with the cookie plugin (as demonstrated [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#cookie)).

I set the path of the cookie using the path option when the tab is created:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ cookie: { path: '/A/' } });
```

In firefox this works correctly. No matter what the url is after "/A/" (ex "A/B/C") the tab control always correctly remembers which tab was last selected and switches to it when I re-load the page.

However, on Chrome (v21), occasionally the browser will add another tab cookie with a different path. I then end up with two cookies, one with the path "/A/" as I originally created, and another one with the path "/A/B/" which is the url I am currently on. Unfortunately, it seems that this "double cookie" causes the wrong tab to sometimes load when the page is refreshed, since the two cookies seem to conflict.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour in chrome? I've tried several programatic solutions (such as forcing the path to "/A/" if the path contains "/A/", but as that code is never reached it seems chrome is doing it automatically).

Thanks for the help!

Seems the problem was that chrome doesn't differentiate between cookies with the same name on different paths; so the other tab control I had in my application was messing things up. Once I gave the cookie a unique name things started working properly!

Comment: Is this issue relevant? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51352&q=cookie%20path%20status%3DUnconfirmed&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: @say2joe Interesting...it looks like my issue is similar.

Comment: Do you have a demo?  If path isn't specified in the cookie definition the current path is assumed and that path specificity overrides your other cookie.  It is possible that something in your code is triggering path not to be set.  If the value is hardcoded, what is the actual value? Is it relative?

Comment: @BrianNickel As my code shows, I'm setting a path when the cookie is defined. The actual value is a relative path, yes. That line there is the only place I reference the cookie, I don't set it or change it in any other way.

Comment: To be clear, that's an absolute path (but relative URL).  I just wanted to check because I don't know if '../A' would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just pushed an [**example**](https://github.com/f0t0n/jQuery-UI-tabs-with-cookie-example) to the GitHub repository.
Seems it's working well in my Chrome 21 under Linux.

[Screenshot of first path](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2uD9Ovt0FTyeHBkTTFQNG9MRW8)

[Screenshot of second path](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2uD9Ovt0FTyV21UZnZfd19SSXc)

If you're using jQuery UI >= 1.7 then add property "name" with some unique value like "my-absolutely-unique-cookie" to your cookie object you're passing and look how it goes:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    cookie: {
        name: 'my-unique-cookie',
        // store cookie for a day, without, it would be a session cookie
        expires: 1,
        path: '/tabs'
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems what you've done is exactly what I DON'T want to happen - I don't want chrome to set another cookie, I want it to accept the one that already exists. I should also mention that at "A/B" there isn't a separate set of tabs, it's the same tabs that exist in "/A/".

Comment: OK, I've just set same cookie path for both URLs (http://goo.gl/iLNg2) and updated the links to my screenshots - you can see that it's anyway is working well - the state of tabs is shared between of all pages under my /tabs path

Comment: I can't figure out what I'm doing differently then...I'm doing the exact same thing yet chrome keeps creating new cookies for every new path.

Comment: Force browser to clear cache. If it doesn't help, try to search in files of project any additional tabs initialization like `$ grep -r ").tabs(" /path/to/project/directory`, maybe somewhere you're re-initializing tabs with wrong paths. Really it's hard to determine blindly without your code on display.

Comment: If you're using jQuery UI >= 1.7 then add property "name" with some unique value like "my-absolutely-unique-cookie" to your cookie object you're passing and look how it goes.

Comment: Looks like that did it! Ugh...I feel stupid...I had noticed earlier that chrome didn't seem to be able to differentiate between cookies of the same name on different paths :(. If you edit your answer to include what you just commented I'll award the bounty/mark as answer.